# Deleting using Inner Join having foreign key

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help with a query.

These are my tables:

```
Table 1 - General

id

name

last_name
```

---

```
Table 2 - User

id

username

table1_Id (This one references to table1 ids) - FK
```

Since my references are on cascade, if I delete table1, it will delete all the others.

But I don't know how to do the query.

I want to get first a Id in Table2 then get Table2.Table1_id , then go to Table1 and delete the Id that I just got.

Comment: what do you want to delete?

Comment: The rows in table1 , i want to get a Id in table2 , then get the table1.id(fk) of that row , and delete in table1 the row with that fk

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from Table1
```

your keys are on cascade, this will also delete all the rows in Table2

you can delete one row from table1 the same as you would normally

```
delete from Table1 where id=to_delete
```

this will cascade and delete the rows in table2 that referenced `to_delete`

ok; edit again

```
delete from Table1 where id=(select table1_id from Table2 where id=group_to_delete)
```

will delete the row from Table1 with the id you get from the row in Table2, which will cascade and delete the rows in Table2 that share the same key.

Comment: Sorry , didnt explained well , i wanna do that , but starting from Table2 , I want to get a Id in Table2 , then get the Table2.Table1_id , then Delete that Id in Table1